# Getting black screen when running IOS simulator on virtual machine

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, ios-simulator

I am using MacOS version 10.15 Beta with Xcode version 11.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that xcode was too new for the Macos version, and was solved by downgrading xcode to 10.3